# How to create queries using runtime managed labels using Neo4j-OGM?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

Simple question: I'm using Neo4-OGM (with Quarkus) to interact with my Neo4J DB (latest version).

I have an entity "Contact" and I added the @Labels to be able to manage extra labels at runtime.

```
@NodeEntity
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = UuidStrategy.class)
    private String identifier;

    // some properties and relations...

    @Labels
    private List<String> labels;

}
```

This will work fine.

But now, I would like to querying my DB using the methods loadAll with Filters instead of writing by myself a cypher query.

Unfortunately, I cannot see how I could get any equivalent of the following cypher query:

```
MATCH (n:`Contact`:`Label_added_in_labels`) RETURN n
```

Is it supported? Or I will have to write the cypher by myself? (That's fine but I don't want to write them if it's not needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Filter` in Neo4j-OGM are property based and sadly cannot help you with this.
But you *could* use the Neo4j CypherDSL if you do not want to write your own statements.

For this you can add the following dependency to your project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-dsl</artifactId>
    <version>2021.3.0</version> // <- currently the latest version
</dependency>
```

and use it for example like this in combination with a Neo4j-OGM `Session`:

```
Node node = Cypher.node("Contact", "Label_added_in_labels");
Statement statement = Cypher.match(node.named("n")).returning(node).build();
Iterable<User> contacts = session.query(Contact.class, statement.getCypher(), Collections.emptyMap());
```